# How to generate list of tuples relating records

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to generate a list from the list of tuples:

```
a = [(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,6), (4,7), (5 6), (5,9), (5,10), (6,7)
             (6.10) (6.11) (7.8) (7.12) (8.12) (9.10) (10.11)]
```

The rule is:
- I have a record from any (`begin = random.choice (a)`)
- Items from the new list must have the following relationship:
     the last item of each tuple in the list must be equal to the first item of the next tuple to be inserted.

Example of a valid output (starting by the tuple (3.1)):

```
[(3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 7), (7, 8), (8, 12), (12, 7), (7, 6), (6, 2), (2, 5), (5, 6), (6, 10), (10, 5) (5, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 6), (6, 3)]
```

How can I do this? Its make using list comprehensions?
Thanks!

Comment: Why was `(6, 7)` not included? Where did `(6, 3)` come from?

Comment: I don't get how you obtain the values after `(8, 12)` in your output. Are you scanning the `a` list backwards? Otherwise the correct output would be just `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 7), (7, 8), (8, 12)]`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, Well, the exact output depends on the random `begin` tuple. But, yes, the output list does not include all the original tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `lisb` will be populated with tuples in the order that you seek. This is, of course, if `lisa` provides appropriate tuples (ie, each tuple has a 1th value matching another tuple's 0th value). Your sample list will not work, regardless of the implementation, because all the values don't match up (for example, there is no 0th element with 12, so that tuple can't be connected forward to any other tuple)...so you should come up with a better sample list.

**Tested, working.**

```
import random

lisa = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3), (4, 0), (0, 9), (9, 1)]
lisb = []

current = random.choice(lisa)

while True:
    lisa.remove(current)
    lisb.append(current)
    current = next((y for y in lisa if y[0] == current[1]), None)
    if current == None:
        break

print lisb
```

If you don't want to delete items from `lisa`, just slice a new list.

Comment: Instead of ```lista.remove(current)```, you could store index of ```current``` and remove it with ```lisa[idx] = lisa[-1]; lisa.pop()```. This remove is not linear, but constant time.

Comment: @kroolik Yes, but list.index() is a linear operation. So, both complexities would end up being linear time.

Comment: after some testing: ```python -m timeit "a = range(100000); a.remove(50000)"``` yields 1.69 msec per loop, ```python -m timeit "a = range(100000); a.remove(1)"``` 986 usec per loop, ```python -m timeit "a = range(100000); a.remove(99999)"``` 2.41 msec per loop. The index switch and pop() yielded 908~ usec in all cases

Answer (score 0):

As a generator function:

```
def chained_tuples(x):
    oldlist = x[::]
    item = random.choice(oldlist)
    oldlist.remove(item)
    yield item

    while oldlist:
        item = next(next_item for next_item in oldlist if next_item[0] == item[1])
        oldlist.remove(item)
        yield item
```

As noted, you'll get an incomplete response if your list isn't actually chainable all the way through, like your example list.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of the answers so far are missing the requirement (at least based on your example output) that the longest chain be found.

My suggested solution is to recursively parse all possible chains that can be constructed, and return the longest result. The function looks like this:

```
def generateTuples(list, offset, value = None):
  if value == None: value = list[offset]
  list = list[:offset]+list[offset+1:]
  res = []
  for i,(a,b) in enumerate(list):
    if value[1] in (a,b):
      if value[1] == a:  
        subres = generateTuples(list, i, (a,b))
      else:
        subres = generateTuples(list, i, (b,a))
      if len(subres) > len(res):
        res = subres
  return [value] + res
```

And you would call it like this:

```
results = generateTuples(a, 1, (3,1))
```

Producing the list:

```
[(3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 7), (7, 8), (8, 12), (12, 7), (7, 6),
 (6, 2), (2, 5), (5, 6), (6, 10), (10, 5), (5, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11),
 (11, 6), (6, 3)]
```

The first parameter of the function is the source list of tuples, the second parameter is the offset of the first element to use, the third parameter is optional, but allows you to override the value of the first element. The latter is useful when you want to start with a tuple in its reversed order as you have done in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another way of solving this problem:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

lisa = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3), (4, 0), (0, 9), (9, 1)]

current_start, current_end = lisa[random.randint(0, len(lisa) - 1)]
starts = defaultdict(list)
lisb = [(current_start, current_end)]

for start, end in lisa:
    starts[start].append(end)

while True:
    if not starts[current_end]:
        break
    current_start, current_end = current_end, starts[current_end].pop()
    lisb.append((current_start, current_end))
```

**Note:** You have to make sure `lisa` is not empty.